# Function with an istream& as parameter and return type in C++

Tags: c++, function, reference, iostream

> I'm trying to understand this code. Can any one help with this example?
>   `//I dont understand point of using istream as argument and as return type`
>   `istream &read(istream &is, Sales_data &item)`
>   `{`
>   `double price = 0;`
>   `is >> item.bookNo >> item.units_sold >> price;`
>   `item.revenue = price * item.units_sold;`
>   `return is;`
>   `}`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't see any `ostream&` parameter. It looks pretty straighforward. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: Would you understand it if it used a particular subclass of `istream`, like `ifstream`? If you would, then you already do.

Answer (score 1):

It reads data from an input stream and uses it to set up a `Sales_data` object. The number of books and units sold are read from the stream and stored directly into the object. Then the unit price is read from the stream, and this data is used to update the revenue in the object.

The stream used is returned from the function. This allows a technique known as function chaining.